# Is the mesenterium a synonym for the mesocolon?

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy

On [biodigital](https://human.biodigital.com) anatomy browser I found a structure called the mesocolon. I didn't find the term in [Uberon](http://www.ontobee.org/search?ontology=UBERON&keywords=mesocolon&submit=Search%20terms) and I'm unclear whether it's simply a synonym for mesenterium or whether it's a separate concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesentery is the name of a whole set of tissues attaching the intestines to the abdominal wall.

In human anatomy, there are three different portions of the mesentery:

- Mesenterium sensu strictu, also called Meso
- Mesocolon transversum
- Mesocolon sigmoideum, also called Mesosigmoideum

Two smaller mesenteries can be found at the appendix (Mesoappendix), and at the cranial part of the rectum (Mesorectum)

So... Mesocolon is a part of the mesentery, but no synonym.

Comment: Could you specify what the term _Mesocolon_ includes?

Comment: Mesocolon includes all mesenteries of only the pelvic colon (Sigmoid colon) and transverse colon. All other parts of the intenstine are held in place either by the Meso or the smaller mesenteries named above.